# how to get start time of an event from android calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

How to get **`StartTime`** and **`EndTime`** from an event from **android calendar**? I am using this code for get all the data of the event but it gives me **`StartDate`** and **`EndDate`** but i need **`Date + Time`** of both **Start** and **End**. here's the code

```
CalNames[i] = "Event" + cursor_event.getInt(0) + ": \nTitle: "
                        + cursor_event.getString(1) + "\nDescription: "
                        + cursor_event.getString(2) + "\nStart Date: "
                        + new Date(cursor_event.getLong(3)) + "\nEnd Date : "
                        + new Date(cursor_event.getLong(4)) + "\nLocation : "
                        + cursor_event.getString(5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cursor_event.getLong(cursor_event.getColumnIndex("dtstart"))` to get time the event starts in UTC millis since epoch.

To get event end time use `cursor_event.getLong(cursor_event.getColumnIndex("dtend"))`

All event columns you can find here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#DTEND

Comment: you mean I have to use cursor_event.getLong(cursor_event.getColumnIndex("dtstart")) instead of new Date(cursor_event.getLong(3)) ???

Comment: That depends on what is your query

Comment: By using your code i am getting the dtstart like this( Starting date is :1385389800000
)could you please solve the problem

Comment: The values you get is in milliseconds since epoch. You can create a usual `java.util.Date` object from it like this: `new Date(startTime);`