# How can I get the start time of an event in the android calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am aware that this is similar to the question here: [how to get start time of an event from android calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222971/how-to-get-start-time-of-an-event-from-android-calendar)

But I am new to android development and I don't really understand what that code is doing because his variables aren't shown being declared.

All I want to do is launch an app that displays the start time of the first (for now) event of a given day(can be hard coded for now, would eventually like to launch calendar app and have user pick the day). I know how to print to the screen, I just need to figure out how to extract the time I need!

```
Calendar cursor_event;
int sTime = cursor_event.getStartTime(); // i just made this method up, but its bacially what i want
```

Answer (score 0):

see this is the full code about some Events of Calendar. may this help you.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
long calID = 0;
long eventID = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

    final String[] projection = { Calendars._ID, Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
            Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME };

    // Submit the query and get a Cursor object back.
    cur = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        String accNme = null;
        String accType = null;
        String disName = null;

        // Get the field values
        calID = cur.getLong(0);
        accNme = cur.getString(1);
        accType = cur.getString(2);
        disName = cur.getString(3);

        Log.v("log_tag", "calId     : " + calID);
        Log.v("log_tag", "accNme    : " + accNme);
        Log.v("log_tag", "accType   : " + accType);
        Log.v("log_tag", "disName   : " + disName);
    }

    /*long startMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2012, 11, 8, 7, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();

    cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DURATION, "P60S");
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "MyTestNew");
    values.put(Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.MAGENTA);
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "India");
    values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=3");
    cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    */

    String[] proj = new String[] { Events._ID, Events.DTSTART,
            Events.DTEND, Events.RRULE, Events.TITLE };

    cur = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String title = null;
        long beginVal = 0;

        eventID = cur.getLong(0);
        beginVal = cur.getLong(1);
        title = cur.getString(4);

        Log.v("log_tag", "Event:  " + title);
        Log.v("log_tag", "eventID:  " + eventID);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(beginVal);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Log.v("log_tag", "DateS: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
        Log.v("log_tag", "DateE: " + cur.getLong(2));
        Log.v("log_tag", "RRULE: " + cur.getString(3));
    }

    /*cr = getContentResolver();
    values = new ContentValues();
    values = new ContentValues();
    uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2");
    values.put(Events.DURATION, "P1S");
    int rows = cr.update(uri, values, null, null);
    Log.v("log_tag", "Rows updated: " + rows);*/

    cur = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String title = null;
        long eventID = 0;
        long beginVal = 0;

        eventID = cur.getLong(0);
        beginVal = cur.getLong(1);
        title = cur.getString(4);

        Log.v("log_tag", "Event:  " + title);
        Log.v("log_tag", "eventID:  " + eventID);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(beginVal);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Log.v("log_tag", "DateS: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
        Log.v("log_tag", "DateE:  " + cur.getLong(2));
        Log.v("log_tag", "RRULE:  " + cur.getString(3));
    }
  }
}
```

took reference from [Here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/)